# Can I get user's phone number by requesting for permission in ios 6?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, permissions, ios6, phone-number

I am building an IOS6 app which requires the user's phone number,

Is there a way to ask the user for permission and get the number in programmatic way?

Or he has to manually type it in?

I am using Xcode 4.5 if it matters..

Comment: No! I asked if this permission type exists! not if it is possible to get it without permission!

Comment: That question asks if it's possible at all, _including_ by asking permission.

Comment: So let my question be a subclass of that one :)

Comment: Right, but subclassed questions should forward all their answers to their superclass so that the information is consolidated. That's the point of closing as duplicate.

Comment: It's funny because I just got this notification: 
You've earned the "Popular Question" badge for Can I get user's phone number by requesting for permission in ios 6?. See your profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get the phone via any easy API within iOS.  There *might* be a way to do it [via the technique described in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591430/getting-the-local-iphone-number-through-sdk), but this is a few years old and Apple may have closed this hole (which uses an undocumented key). I also wonder if Apple wouldn't allow the app on the App Store for privacy reasons. [Probably not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios).

You'll have to trust the user to type in the correct phone number if you prompt him/her to.

Comment: That is so weird, isn't it exactly the reason permission exists? So apps will be able to ask permission for user's private data? :)