# How to retrieve the cell number from an iPhone through Xcode?

Tags: ios

Is it possible for an iOS app to retrieve the cell number of an iPhone? It is possible on Android but I am not sure about iOS. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean cell phone number or GCM-Cell id number? (the id of the cell tower used for triangulation your position)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios seems to be the authoritative answer to this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to get the phone number of the device. Apple doesn't allow this, and it would be bad for users if app developers were easily able to get this somehow, for privacy reasons. The best way to deal with this is ask the user for it if you really want it.

There used to be ways to get the device phone number, but they were basically loopholes, or bugs in iOS, which allowed this. Apple has since fixed these, and it's very obvious that if any new methods were discovered, Apple would be fixing those as well. So it's best to just go the only route that will forever be allowed, which, again, is to ask the user.

Comment: I guess I will just politely ask the user :). Thank you for your help

Comment: @user2771924 Since it was helpful to you, would you mind up voting and accepting my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the cell phone number, see this question: [Can I get user's phone number by requesting for permission in ios 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296057/can-i-get-users-phone-number-by-requesting-for-permission-in-ios-6)

In short, probably not.